# discord.net how to get user input data on slash command option?

Tags: discord.net

```cs
var guildCommand = new SlashCommandBuilder();
guildCommand.WithName("question")
.AddOption("answer", ApplicationCommandOptionType.String, "your answer", isRequired: true);
```

I created a slash command with option to get user input data like this.

```cs
public async Task EchoUserAnswer(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    await command.RespondAsync("Your answer is {UserAnswer}");
}
```

And I added this method on SlashCommandExecuted event.

I want to know how to get user answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```cs
public async Task EchoUserAnswer(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    var userInput = command.Data.Options.First().Value.ToString();
    await command.RespondAsync($"Your answer is {userInput}");
}
```