# Recieving user input with slash command Discord.Net

Tags: discord.net

Is there a way to receive user inputted data using the current format I have, I have seen that there is a way to do it using the slashCommandBuilder as seen here [discord.net how to get user input data on slash command option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043615/discord-net-how-to-get-user-input-data-on-slash-command-option) , an example of my slash command is

[SlashCommand("ping", "ping pong")]

```
    public async Task HandlePing()
    {
        
        await RespondAsync("pong!");
        
    }
```

I'd like to be able to use user input eg: user inputs /ping dog and it prints dog

Comment: Just add a parameter to the method signature for the input.

Answer (score 0):

there was another post like this; use the following code:

```
public async Task HandlePing(SocketSlashCommand command)
{
    var userInput = command.Data.Options.First().Value.ToString();
    await command.RespondAsync("pong!");
}
```

If your input is IUser, or an int, remove ToString() at the end of the variable, userInput

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).